# How to preserve layer settings when copying between files

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have two illustrator projects that represent a warehouse floor layout. Both projects have the same layers (same names, same color).

One project is the entire floor layout on one artboard and the other project has 8 artboards that I've used to break things apart to make viewing easier.

I have a lot of updates from the single artboard project that I want to move over, but every time I do this all of the objects end up on the same layer. It just puts them all on the currently selected layer of the project I am copying to. I've tried keyboard copy shortcut for this as well as floating my other project on another monitor and doing a alt+click to clone. End result is the same, all objects in one layer.

Is it possible for me to copy between projects and have my objects stay on the proper layer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Layer Panel menu, choose `Paste Remembers Layers`. Then when you copy/paste between files, the layers will remain in tact.

[image: Menu for Layers Panel]

Comment: Would this be the same for copying layers between Indesign and Illustrator?

Comment: Please @Brynn, where do you get this menu?

Comment: @Luc-Olivier it is the menu on the **Layers Panel**.

Answer (score -1):

This is for modern Illustrator:

Edit -> Paste in place

Comment: That only preserves position, not layer structure. You need to check the option mentioned in the other answer to do that.